# Delegated AppCatalog.Read.All needs admin consent when requested using @azure/msal-browser

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

How can I use the [@azure/msal-browser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/%40azure/msal-browser) package to request a delegated permission when there is both a delegated and application version of the permission?

The permission I am trying to request is `AppCatalog.Read.All` which has a delegated version not requiring admin consent and an application version which does. This can be seen on the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/%40azure/msal-browser) and in the images below.

When I make the request using the code sample below, the user (who is not an azure admin) is unable to consent and is presented with a message asking for an admin to log in and consent.

Is there a way to specifically request the delegated version of `AppCatalog.Read.All`

Cheers

```js
 const config: Configuration = {
    auth: {
        clientId: process.env.AppId
    },
    cache: {
        cacheLocation: "sessionStorage",
        storeAuthStateInCookie: false,
    },
};
const request: RedirectRequest = {
    scopes: ["AppCatalog.Read.All"],
};

const client = new PublicClientApplication(config);
try {
    const data = await client.handleRedirectPromise();
    if (data?.accessToken) 
        authentication.notifySuccess(data.accessToken);
    else
        client.loginRedirect(request);
} catch (error) {
    authentication.notifyFailure(error);
}
```

[image: Delegated permission]

[image: Application permission]

Comment: If you go to `Azure AD` > `Enterprise Applications` > `Consent and permissions` (in the Security group), which option is configured for `User consent for applications`?

Comment: Thanks @scottwtang, this is for a teams application that a different tenancy would be using. Ideally they would be able to consent through the application without having to go into Azure Portal

Comment: My question is because based on the setting configured, it may not be possible for a user to consent to the permission, even if it's a delegated permission.

Comment: @scottwtang - Apologies, I read the question completely wrong. The tenancy I am testing on does have "Allow user consent for apps" enabled, sadly.

Comment: Microsoft changed the default settings to “users can consent to some permissions”. The scope you’re requesting might not be included in the default consentable scopes.